# too much recursion - jquery - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-login

I am struggling with this issue for a couple of hours, but no sign of success. I am trying to implement the facebook login. this is my code:

```
function fblogin() {
 FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        var url = '/me?fields=name,email';
        FB.api(url, function(response) {
            $('#email_login').val(response.email);
            $('#pwd_login').val(response.name);
            $('#sess_id').val(response.id);
            if($('#evil_username').val()==""){
                $('#loginform').submit();
            }else{
             // doh you are bot
            }
        });
    } else {
        // cancelled
     }
  }, {scope:'email'});
 }
```

but once i click facebook login button, i am getting `too much recursion` in console. why is that? i read lots of problems here in stackoverflow regarding this issue, but couldnot find the clue for my case.

i dont have recursion here, but what is happening which causes that recursion?

and there is a call for it from

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
  appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
  channelUrl : '//www.mydomain.de/channel.html', 
  status     : true, 
  cookie     : true, 
  xfbml      : true  
});
// Additional init code here
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // connected
} else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // not_authorized
      fblogin();
} else {
      // not_logged_in
      fblogin();
}
});
};
```

and also from normal `LOGIN` button which triggers the `fblogin()`.

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: set `event.preventBubble = true`

Comment: @SLaks, please see my update. i added the code of how i call fblogin()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i don't see where your onclick code is or the action that calls `fblogin()` and i'm assuming the problem is when `fblogin()` gets called.

```
 function fblogin(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
```

add an event parameter to each function `fblogin(event)` call so this can be cross browser compatible.

when an event occurs, it traverses to parent elements so they can inherit the event handler, in your case `function fblogin()`. when you stop propagation `stopPropagation()` you stop DOM traversing and the element that calls the function won't pass the handler to the parent if `stopPropagation` is set. that all means the browser will stop looping through all your DOM elements and making your jquery less recursive.

Comment: thanks jay, very useful information. can you please explain me what this will do?

Comment: @doniyor are you using the latest jquery version?

Comment: yes, i am using, latest jquery. but now it is working, thank you soooo much.